# For each row with same from_address, find max value in column contact_id and update every row with this from_address to max contact_id value

Tags: mysql

I have a database with table contacts with clients list and a table `helpdesk_tickets` where each row represents one helpdesk ticket from the client.

The error occurred in the software and the duplicates were created in table contacts (all data same except the id). In effect, in table `helpdesk_tickets` some e-mails were assigned to different client ids. I'd like to assign all tickets from the same e-mail address to the latest `client_id`. This gives me the lastest `client_id` for each ticket (basing on the `from_email` column in `helpdesk_tickets`):

```
SELECT from_address,  MAX(contact_id) as a FROM helpdesk_tickets GROUP BY from_address HAVING COUNT(contact_id)>1;
```

Now I need to update every row with the same `from_address` to the max value from the selection above. How to?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an update join here:

```sql
UPDATE helpdesk_tickets ht1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT from_address, MAX(contact_id) AS max_contact_id
    FROM helpdesk_tickets
    GROUP BY from_address
) ht2
    ON ht2.from_address = ht1.from_address
SET
    contact_id = ht2.max_contact_id
WHERE
    contact_id <> ht2.max_contact_id;
```